# how to close one tab with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a code that when you run, it waits for 2 hours displays a video waits  then closes.
***here it is :***

```
import time
import webbrowser
import os

total_breaks = 3
breaks_taken = 0
while breaks_taken < total_breaks:
    time.sleep(30)
    print('you have taken a break at:' + time.ctime())
    webbrowser.open("https://youtu.be/-qlJiGGvPUI")
    time.sleep(12)
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
    breaks_taken += 1
```

But I saw that it closes the whole browser (chrome) but I want to close the tab opened.
I use windows 10 and python 2.7.14.
I really need simple answers.(a new student)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot close a tab via a taskkill, this is because the [task is not a 1:1 relation to the tab](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models)

For a more elaborate answer read [this](https://superuser.com/a/306715)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pynput` to control your keyboard
and at the end of session, use `ctrl + w` to close the tab (for Chrome)